# How does partitioning step acts as a conquering step in quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, theory

Time complexity for recurrence relations is given by :
`T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)` here `f(n)` is the cost of conquering the sub-problems i.e. cost of merging
all the sub-problems in order to solve the problem but in case of partioning we are dividing the array around a particular pivot point so while calculating the time complexity of quick-sort why do we take `O(n)`
time for `f(n)`.

How is this acting as a conquering step?

Comment: I don't understand the question; do you find it confusing that the input is rearranged before the actual smaller instances are generated?

Comment: No I am just asking that f(n) is considered to be the time taken to merge the solutions of the sub-problem to give solution of the entire problem so it should be considered as the cost of conquering the problem for divide and conquer algorithm but in case of quick sort the partitioning algorithm actually partitions the array around a pivot so where is it conquering the entire problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand what you mean by conquering step.

`f(n)` is in fact the cost of anything done in your recursive function, that happens well before, after, or between your recursions.

In the case of quick sort, the cost of merging the solutions of the partitions is 0, as you don't need to do anything after the left and right sides of the pivot are sorted. The whole cost is in producing the partitions, and to do that, you need to position your selected pivot. This is why quick sort is classified as a Hard Split Easy Join kind of Divide and Conquer.

The cost of positioning the pivot is `O(n)`, as you have to move from left to right and from right to left, finding items in the wrong side of the pivot, and swapping them, until both searches (from left to right and from right to left) cross each other.

Hope this helped in your understanding, and sorry if I misunderstood completely your question.

Comment: Yes I got your explanation actually I was thinking f(n) to be the cost of conquering the problem using divide and conquer strategy ,so I though that since aT(n/b) is the cost of dividing the entire problem to a sub-problems so f(n) must be the cost of merging all the solutions to give one solution to the problem ,Now I got the definition of f(n) from your explanation .

Comment: But I am still confused by the definition of T(n) which is the time taken to solve a problem using divide and conquer strategy , so T(n)= time taken to divide the problem to sub-problems +Time taken to combine the solution of all the sub-problems to one give the solution to one problem , so this combining step actually made me stucked and that's why I thought partitioning step to be a conquering step

Comment: The T(n) function as you provided, is the generic form of any recurrence solvable with the Master Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). By conquering cost I believe you mean the cost of solving the partitions, and that happens inside the T(n/b).